# CSS animation-name to be specific on animation-fill-mode

Tags: html, css

So lately I try to make an animation with CSS where it makes a specific class opacity from 0% to 100%. But I got some problem with the animation on `class="bar"`.

So as we can see the `animation-fill-mode` is not only applied to the title animation which will change the oppacity, but it applies to the bar animation too. Is there any way to specific `animation-fill-mode` 's animation name?

These are the codes that I use to make it.

```css
@keyframes title {
    from {-webkit-opacity: 0%;}
    to {-webkit-opacity: 100%;}
}

@keyframes bar {
    0% {height: 12px;}
    50% {height: 33px;}
    100% {height: 12px;}
    from {-webkit-opacity: 0%;}
    to {-webkit-opacity: 100%;}
}

.musicBox {
    opacity: 0
    -moz-animation-name: title;
    -moz-animation-duration: 3s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 3s;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
    -webkit-animation-name: title;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 3s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -o-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -ms-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards; 
}

.musicBox {
    background-color: white;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    border-radius: 12px;
    padding: 3px;
    width: 64px;
    margin: auto;
}

.image {
    height: 64px;
    width: 64px;
    position: relative;
}

.musicImg {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 8px;
    opacity: 90%;
}

.spectrum {
    position: absolute;
    inset: 0 0 0 0;
    border-radius: 8px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.bar {
    width: 6px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 3px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    animation: bar 2100ms infinite;
}

.bar:nth-child(even) {
    animation-delay: 700ms;
}
```

```html
<div class="musicBox">
  <div class="image">
    <img class="musicImg" src="https://media.wired.com/photos/5ed67e71b818b223fd84195f/1:1/w_1600,h_1600,c_limit/Blackout-hashtag-activism.jpg">
    <div class="spectrum">
      <div class="bar"></div>
      <div class="bar"></div>
      <div class="bar"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: FYI, you don't need any of those vendor prefixes unless you're supporting IE9. (I really hope you're not supporting IE9.) See https://caniuse.com/?search=animation-delay, for example.

Comment: *but it applies to the bar animation too* --> it's not

Comment: @TemaniAfif is right, it doesn't apply to `.bar`. Even if it was, all you would have to do is put `.bar { animation-fill-mode: initial; }` or whatever fill mode your want on `.bar`. I suppose you wanted to ask something else. Also about opacity, it forcibly change childrens opacity. Nothing you can do about that. Apart from changing HTML structure, or find something else than opacity, like background-color.

Comment: Could you describe what the problem with the animation on .bar actually is?

Comment: @AHaworth as you can see on the snippet, the three bar oppacity animation keep changing rather than stay at 100% after the ```@keyframes title``` ran.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a containing div around the `<div class="musicBox"></div>` you can use `>` in css which means that the styles will only be applied to elements which are a direct child of the first class specified. I used `.musicContainer > .musicBox` as my selector so the fade animation now only applies to the div with `musicBox` as its immediate child.

```css
@keyframes title {
    from {-webkit-opacity: 0%;}
    to {-webkit-opacity: 100%;}
}

@keyframes bar {
    0% {height: 12px;}
    50% {height: 33px;}
    100% {height: 12px;}
    from {-webkit-opacity: 0%;}
    to {-webkit-opacity: 100%;}
}

.musicContainer > .musicBox {
    opacity: 0
    -moz-animation-name: title;
    -moz-animation-duration: 3s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 3s;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
    -webkit-animation-name: title;
    -webkit-animation-delay: 3s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -o-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    -ms-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards; 
}

.musicBox {
    background-color: white;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    border-radius: 12px;
    padding: 3px;
    width: 64px;
    margin: auto;
}

.image {
    height: 64px;
    width: 64px;
    position: relative;
}

.musicImg {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 8px;
    opacity: 90%;
}

.spectrum {
    position: absolute;
    inset: 0 0 0 0;
    border-radius: 8px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.bar {
    width: 6px;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 3px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    animation: bar 2100ms infinite;
}

.bar:nth-child(even) {
    animation-delay: 700ms;
}
```

```html
<div class="musicContainer">
  <div class="musicBox">
    <div class="image">
      <img class="musicImg" src="https://media.wired.com/photos/5ed67e71b818b223fd84195f/1:1/w_1600,h_1600,c_limit/Blackout-hashtag-activism.jpg">
      <div class="spectrum">
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
        <div class="bar"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```